# Can a springboot java 1.8 project be ran with jdk 13?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an existing springboot project from git that has java 1.8 the properties of the pom.xml, my current work pc has java 13 installed. Will i still be able to work effectively in my situation as in run my application without errors, etc.

Comment: By the way, under the six-month release cadence for modern Java, support of Java 13 has ended. Consider using either the latest (Java 15, soon to be Java 16 in March with early-release available now), or the current long-term support (LTS) version (Java 11).

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking if you will generally have a problem with migrating a Spring Boot project from 1.8 to 13, or are you concerned with a specific property value in a `pom.xml`.  file?

Each JDK version advance is generally backward compatible with prior versions.  You should not have any trouble getting a project that is running correctly under 1.8 to run under 13.

With this said, there might be a small change that you have to make if a properties file or pom.xml file is specifying a particular JDK version.  If that's the case, you should be able to just change the value of that property to reflect the version of the JDK you are using.

If you need a more specific answer, you should show us the `pom.xml` file that you are concerned about.

Comment: Excellent answer! thank you. I wanted to install Java 8 because there is an error when mvn installing -> "The POM for...is missing, no dependency information available" and my jdk installer won't start for some reason. I was afraid it was the Java version.